# Pass parameter within LI element to jQuery droppable

Tags: jquery, html

Can I add a parameter to an LI element so that I can then retrieve it within the droppable in jQuery

Currently I have :

```
drop: function(event, ui) { 
   var theText = ui.draggable.text();
}
```

But I need to access a parameter within the LI element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example program. It may help you for your requirement

```
        $(document).ready(initialize);
        function initialize() 
        {
            $("#divFields li").draggable
            ({
                helper: "clone"
            });


            $("#divDroppedFields").droppable
            ({
                accept: "#divFields li",
                drop: function (event, ui)
                {
                    $(this).find('#txtMessageFields').append((ui.draggable.attr('data-value')));                        
                }
            });
        }


    <div id="divFields">
        <ul>
            <li data-value="data1">iPhone</li>
            <li data-value="data2">iPod</li>
            <li data-value="data3">iPad</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


  <div id="divDroppedFields" class="ui-widget-content">
        <textarea id="txtMessageFields" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `data-*` attribute to your `li` tag or you could put an `input[type=hidden]` inside the `li` and store the parameter there.

Comment: Can this parameter then be access within the drop jQuery function ?

Comment: You could access the `data-*` attribute using jquery's `attr()` function, and probably use something like `$(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val()` to get the value of a hidden input within your `li`.